# Asp.net dropdownlist selected value without viewstate How does PHP achieve this

Tags: php, asp.net, drop-down-menu, viewstate

This is just a question that popped out of no where from my mind,

**PHP does not have viewstate**, but how do those guys get to save the `country id` during `postback/POST` if a dropdownlist is bound to datasource below

```
CountryId CountryName
1             USA
2             INDIA
3            ....
```

assuming text displayed is CountryName.

In ASP.NET during the postback the dropdownlist selected value is loaded from viewstate as the datasource is saved into viewstate during databinding.

- How does PHP actually achieve this effect
- If an error occured during post(validation, etc), asp.net loads the dropdown values from viewstate again, So do the PHP guys request the DB again for countries or load it from cache.

**note:** this is just a simple example where predictable answers could be given, i am looking for more broad minded answer think about other things that dropdownlist can hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, the current value of any/all mutable form elements will be POSTed back to the server and will appear in the [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) global.

UPDATE: an example:

```
<input type="text" name="my_text" value="some_value" ?>
<select name="my_select">
    <option value="option1"/>Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2" SELECTED/>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

In this case, the server will receive:

```
$_POST['my_text'] = 'some_value';
$_POST['my_select'] = 'option2';
```

As per validation: unless your using a framework that introduces validation, PHP doesn't know the difference. If you want to ensure that your select value is indeed a valid one, you need to double check it, manually, against a list of know values.

Again - there are frameworks that introduce lots of help with validation (amongst) other things. There under-the-hood concept though is the same: generate a list, create a select from it, generate the list again and ensure that the POST'ed value is indeed in the list.

Comment: Does that mean u get `ID = 1` when `USA is selected?`. Did you ever wondered how PHP does it?

Comment: Question one solved(PHP relies solely on stateless HTTP, wonderful), question 2 what happens when validation fails(malicious user has added another `option` to `select` through javascript) how would you validate that.